# Status of edited files with certain extensions do not update in Windows10 File Explorer

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

I am editing and saving file content in a Windows 10 environment, working in a `C:\Apps\ApplicationName\` directory.  When I edit a file using a standard extension such as `*.txt`, or `*.doc`, the time and date of the last edited status changes immediately in File Explorer upon saving the file.  But when I edit text files with extensions of `*.rfid`, or `*.enc` the time/date of last edit do not update.  I know the actual file status changes in Windows as shown by the following image:

[image]

When hovering over the file, the correct last edited date can be clearly seen, while the incorrect `2/9/2021 7:50` time date is displayed in the Explorer application.

I have attempted this running a normally opened Windows Explorer, and when  elevated *Run as Admin* with same results.

Note also behavior is different depending on what directory.  For example in: `C:\Dev\ApplicationName\`, edited `*.rfid` and `*.enc` status updates just fine.

So the problem appears to be a combination of unrecognized file type, coupled with directory location.

Is there a Windows setting that can be changed to allow non-standard file types to be recognized in all Windows 10 directories, and updated when edited?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is a little embarrassing, but I'll post it anyway just in case someone else has run into the same thing...

The problem was with the view setting in File Explorer for the `C:\Apps\ApplicationName\` directory. (right clicking the top of any column in File Explorer will present a popup selection of different columns to display) Mine was set to the following:

[image]

which results in this view: (note the date of OPERATOR.ENC)

[image]

Setting it to use ***Date modified*** results in the following:

[image]

Comment: No reason to be embarassed, the `Date` column in **Explorer** can be confusing. The correspoinding property is [`System.ItemDate`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/properties/props-system-itemdate), which can take on the value of different date properties of the file in the "hope" that it is the most relevant to the file type.

Comment: @keith Miller - thanks. This property seems to be defaulted  differently for different directories.. In my   'DevPhys' dir paths the 'Date modified' values were shown automatically.

Comment: `DateModified` and `ItemDate` are *two different properties*. Some *FolderTypes* ( `Generic`, `Documents`, `Music`, etc. ) have a default view that specifies the `ItemDate`column, and others have a default view that specifies the `DateModified` column. I think that's the behavior you're describing.